# Read CSV into Matrix in Spark Shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a ~1GB csv file (but am open to other data types e.g parquet), with 5m rows and 23 columns that I want to read into Spark so that I can multiply it to create a scoring matrix.

On a smaller version of the file I currently using this process:

```
// csv -> array -> Dense Matrix

import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Matrix, Matrices, Dense Matrix}
val test = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/hdfs/landing/test/scoreTest.csv").getLines.toArray.flatmap(._split(",")).map(_.toDouble)
val m1: DenseMatrix  = new DenseMatrix(1000,23,test)
```

Then I can multiply `m1` with `m1.multiply()` which is all fine. However when I try this with the large file I run into memory error exceptions and other issues, even though the file is only 1GB.

Is this the best way to create a matrix object in spark ready for multiplication? The whole read in as array, then convert to DenseMatrix seems unnecessary and is causing memory issues.

Very new to scala/spark so any help is appreciated.

Note: I know that this could be done in memory in python, R, matlab etc but this is more a proof of concept so that it can be used for much larger files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **distrubuted** matrix implementation in `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed`, this uses the `RDD` API and you'll gonna benefit from the parallelism offered by spark.

Please refer to the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#distributed-matrix) for more information.

I'd also recommend you to read [this blog](https://www.thinkbiganalytics.com/2015/11/23/scalable-matrix-multiplication-using-spark-2/) entitled **Scalable Matrix Multiplication using Spark**